# How to iterate over array in handlebar template without defined name in model

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I have model:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "email": "xx@vflbg.com"
  },
  {
    "ID": 6495,
    "email": "email@monkey.com"
  }
]
```

Code for iterating in handlebars:

```
   {{#each xxx}}
    <p>{{email}}</p>
   {{/each}}
```

how do I define xxx ?

If JSON had name in model like:

```
   users: [
      {
        "ID": 5,
        "email": "xx@vflbg.com"
      },
      {
        "ID": 6495,
        "email": "email@monkey.com"
      }
    ]
```

I would simple iterate in handlebars like:

```
   {{#each users}}
    <p>{{email}}</p>
   {{/each}}
```

Comment: I'd recommend changing your accepted answer to Dave Stibrany's answer below.  Definitely seems like the better way to do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have this:

```
var a = [
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "email": "xx@vflbg.com"
  },
  {
    "ID": 6495,
    "email": "email@monkey.com"
  }
];
```

Then just supply the desired name when you call the compiled template:

```
var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
var h = t({ users: a });
```

That will leave you with your desired HTML in `h`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZgVjz/

If you have a collection built from the data:

```
var c = new C(a);
```

Then you'd call the template like this:

```
var h = t({ users: c.toJSON() });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uF3tj/

Comment: This works, but the answer from [Dave Stibrany](http://stackoverflow.com/users/546741/dave-stibrany) [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17329692/591374) is a much better solution.

Answer (score 34):

This works too:

```
{{#each this}}
<p>{{email}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: where to specify the list